# Custom taxonomy does not display in custom post loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

So I think I might be going mad or something. I have a custom post type (arkiv) with two custom taxonomies (genre and author) and I try to list the posts on a template page within a loop and display the post title and the two taxonomies, but I can't get it working. The post title is listed but not the taxonomies.

My CPT looks like this:

```
function post_archive() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'Alla Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'Visa Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Lägg till Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Lägg till Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Ändra Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Uppdatera Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Sök Arkiv & Samlingar', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Fann inget', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Fann inget i Papperskorgen', 'twentytwenty' ),
  ); 
  $args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'arkiv', 'twentytwenty' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-book',
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'show_in_rest'        => true,
    'taxonomies'          => array('genre', 'author'),
  );   
  register_post_type( 'arkiv', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'post_archive', 0 );
```

And my two taxonomies looks like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'genre', 0 );
function genre() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Subjects', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Subject', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Subjects' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Subjects' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Subject' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Subject:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Subject' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Subject' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Subject' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Subject Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Subjects' ),
  );    
  register_taxonomy('genre',array('arkiv'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
  ));
}
```

```
add_action( 'init', 'author', 0 );
function author() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Subjects', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Subject', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Subjects' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Subjects' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Subject' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Subject:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Subject' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Subject' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Subject' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Subject Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Subjects' ),
  );    
  register_taxonomy('author',array('arkiv'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'author' ),
  ));
}
```

My CPT shows up and the taxonomies too, they are there and I assign taxonomies to the posts in there but then when trying to list the posts I only get the post titles but no taxonomies whatsoever

My query:

```
<?php $args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'arkiv', 
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  'orderby' => 'date', 
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'author', 'Author: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
    <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'genre', 'Genre: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
    
  <?php endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can't understand what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't exposed the global `$post` variable after calling `$the_query->the_post()`.

Either add `global $post` right after calling `$the_query->the_post()`, or replace `$post->ID` with `get_the_ID()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it :)